# Balancing IIS compression with CPU time?

Tags: compression, iis-6

For instance, with a level of IIS compression set to 9, the web browsing is significantly faster.  However, I also have a Web Services application on the box, which transfers significant amounts of data (e.g. 3MB payload is typical), it actually takes 20-30% longer for the data to get to the client, because the CPU on the server takes a while to compress it.

Is there a rule of thumb for the level of IIS compression vs amount of data transfered?

Anecdotal experience is welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ran some benchmarks and no matter how you slice it, **turning off compression results in faster performance** for my use case.  Here are the result for a web service call that returns 3.2 megabytes of data (mostly list of things deserialized into byte arrays)

```
Compression  Bandwidth  Time
Level       (KB)       (seconds)
9           1,174      4.2
8           1,174      2.2
7           1,172      1.625
6           1,174      1.5
5           1,181      1.39
4           1,213      1.344
3           1,441      1.375
2           1,490      1.344
1           1,548      1.312
0           1,554      1.312

No         3,226      1.266
Compression
```

The CPU is pretty pegged at level 9 for the duration of the web service call, not so bad at level 8 and anything beneath that is in single digits utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful, because there are so many variables:

- client/server connection speed
- CPU speed and workload
- Type of data (entropy)
- ...

I expect the connection is fairly speedy in your use case? Compressing 3MB shouldn't take all that long after all.